# TextInputEditText top of text input cut off android

Tags: android, styles, android-textinputlayout

I have Text Field with some styles applyed to change the background aspect.
For some reason the input text when writing is cut off.

One solution i found was to increase the overall height, but i would like to keep the 50dp height

The Text Field:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/add_description_layout"
    style="@style/OutlinedRoundedBox"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:hint="@string/add_trans_description_title"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/add_description_input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:inputType="textAutoComplete"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

The styles i am using on the text field:

```
<style name="OutlinedRoundedBox" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">
        @style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.TextInputLayout.Rounded
    </item>
    <item name="boxBackgroundColor">@color/secondaryColor</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeWidth">0dp</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/secondaryDarkColor</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/backgroundText</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/backgroundText</item>
    <item name="hintTextColor">@color/backgroundText</item>
    <item name="hintTextAppearance">@style/TextInputLayoutHintText</item>
    <item name="helperTextTextAppearance">@style/TextInputLayoutHelperText</item>
    <item name="android:theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox.CustomFont</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeOverlay.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox.CustomFont" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="editTextStyle">@style/TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox.CustomFont</item>
</style>

<style name="TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox.CustomFont" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/fira_sans</item>
</style>

<style name="TextInputLayoutHintText" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Hint">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/fira_sans</item>
</style>

<style name="TextInputLayoutHelperText" parent="TextAppearance.Design.HelperText">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/fira_sans</item>
</style>

<style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.TextInputLayout.Rounded" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">32dp</item>
</style>
```

Current aspect:

[image]

[image]

Is there a way around this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think this is to be expected. By default android uses 14sp text size and the height you specified might not be enough for the text size. You can try using small text size with attribute `android:textSize` for **TextInputEditText**